# Threading in client-server socket program - proxy sever

Tags: java, http, sockets, client-server

I am trying to write a program that acts as a proxy server.
Proxy server basically listens to a given port (7575) and sends the request to the server.
As of now, I did not implement caching the response.

The code looks like

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(7575);   
Socket clientSocket = socket.accept(); 
clientRequestHandler(clientSocket);
```

I changed the above code as below: //calling the same clientRequestHandler method from inside another method.

```
Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(client));
serverThread.start();

class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket client){
        this.clientSocket = client;
    }
    @Override
    public void run () {
        try {
            PrxyServer.clientRequestHandler(clientSocket);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Using the code, I am able to open a webpage like google. However, if I open another web page even I completely receive the first response, I get connection reset by peer expection.

**1. How can I handle this issue**
Can I use threading to handle different requests. Can someone give a reference where I look for example code that implements threading.

Comment: Perhaps [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860362/write-http-proxy-in-java) may be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps if you post the code that actually gets this exception you may get some enlightenment.